CRuX - Missing Origin Level Data - starting Sept 2024
I have noticed that the origin data for www(dot)halfords(dot)com is missing since 10th September 2024, there is no redirect in the URL and there is more than sufficient traffic on the website. Something happened last week since that there is no Origin data available.
However all the individual URLs have real user metrics, and the less popular domain www(dot)halfords(dot)ie also has origin data but not www(dot)halfords(dot)com.
I have tried using pagespeed API and https://pagespeed.web.dev/, but there is no Origin data in either.
Please could someone help with this, as the origin level data is very important for reporting.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
